# Hadoop: setting MapReduce resource permissions

Tags: unix, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, user-permissions

Given we have some Hadoop MapReduce task to be run. This MapReduce needs to access some system resources on local drive, i.e. on some node (in fact, we have to place that resources to all nodes).

A question is: which permissions should be given to that resource file?

I would like to give it permissions to be read by the user which runs Hadoop. But in fact the task will be executed under another user. That user is 'yarn'. I.e. if I want to place some resources to some home folder of user which runs Hadoop Job, or related Oozie job etc I cannot do it because in fact home folder of the user which owns MapReduce is /home/yarn/.

What is the best way to deal with this issue?
How do I control under which user MapReduce runs?
Where can I lookup that settings?

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is to create the required folders for such resources  in HDFS, and set the permissions to those folders and the contained files using 'hadoop fs -chmod ..' command.

Please refer this below link:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

Comment: Marco, in our case its not possible to put that files to HDFS for security reasons. They should be read from cluster nodes.

Comment: Did you try change owner of that folder to yarn using chown and do a chmod 644 ?

Answer (score 0):

First off the statement "MapReduce needs to access some system resources on local drive" **is not possible** when running a MapReduce program in distributed mode. Whatever file you need **should be moved to HDFS**. Give the file a read permission to all users I hope everything should be fine. If you need to read the file in the Mapper or Reducer and not pass the file as the input to the MapReduce program then consider using Distributed Cache mechanism provided my MapReduce.